# How to add parameter to ASP.net page

Tags: c#, asp.net, database, parameters

I have a database of some records of the users of my website, such as Name, Email, Address  etc. I have created a page using ASP.net (C#), which can display the information of the user in arranged manner. I want to display that page with information when anyone click the user name from list. How can I add parameter with the page? so that I can fetch data from database using name or ID linked in the list with user name.

What I am trying to do is something like this:

```
example.com/userpage.aspx/XYZ
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use a Query String parameter:

```
example.com/userpage.aspx?id=XYZ
```

Access the id on the server using the QueryString Collection on the Request object:

```
string id = Request.QueryString["id"];
```

Answer (score 2):

I think you would want to use the [ASP.NET Routing engine](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc668201.aspx) to take part of the URL and route it to a parameter.

You could set up your route to be like example.com/page.aspx?id=xyz equals example.com/page/xyz instead

Answer (score 1):

If you are using classic ASP.NET, then you have to pass parameter to query string as Xander suggest. ASP.NET correctly parses parameters after ? and you can access them via Request["parameterName"].

But if you want "user friendly url" like you posted, then you need some mechanism to rewrite user friendly url to system url.

- First of all, you can use IIS7 Url Rewrite module or any 3d party Url
  Rewrite module. Usually it is based on regular expressions and can
  rewrite url /Users/XYZ to /Users.aspx?name=XYZ
- Also you can use relatively new technology ASP.NET Rounting Engine
  like Ryan suggested.
- If your url scheme is complex and you can not describe it with
  regular expressions, then you may write your own HTTP Module and
  perform some custom rewrite rules.

If your Users.aspx.cs page you can read query parameter from Request["Name"], and use it value to perform some SQL query (or whatever you yse to access database)

Answer (score 0):

If you are using GridView, you just need to attach OnRowCommand event to it and then on click of the link you can pass the name an UserID that you want to show over page.